# What do the numbers at the top of LCARS indicate?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, lcars

In the picture below, I've circled (or rather 'rectangled') the numbers above a screen of LCARS.  Now, this picture isn't from *Star Trek: The Next Genreation* itself, but it is an accurate representation.  Often, you see at the top of the screen that these numbers are constantly changing.  **What, if anything, were these numbers supposed to represent?**

[image]

Comment: I think I should get a +1 just for my ground-breaking freehand-rectangle ;)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, they're just nonsense.

Comment: @Richard I'd be particularly interested though if there was some intended meaning behind it

Comment: They indicate that user interface designers of the future think [this](http://www.lingscars.com) is an example of the best that computer information display can get.

Comment: I always thought they're a display of those 'matrices' the crewmen talk about from time to time. Not like anyone quickly picks out a bunch of numbers from a table to make space science outta it or repair a warp drive with it though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Michael Okuda has indicated in [various interviews](http://www.lcarscom.net/okuda9711.htm) that the numbers are pretty much nonsense. They were [never intended to be read in detail](http://www.trektoday.com/interviews/okuda_qa.shtml) (due to the quality of TV film stock). The fact that you can read them at all is a result of unexpected rises in film quality over the intervening years.

> **Moderator:** *Speaking of Okudagrams:  to : Speaking of that, what's the significance of the number 3069 which
>   constantly appears on displays?*
>
> **MichaelOkuda:** *A lot of graphics are rebuilt from earlier graphics, part of our attempt to save time while maintaining graphic
>   consistency.*
>
> **MichaelOkuda:** *That's just a piece that's been recycled.*
>
> **MichaelOkuda:** *Either that or it is a top secret Starfleet Command encryption code.*